# How to use MySQL in terminal?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL,on my Ubuntu 16.04.
I am learning from J.Murach's book.So the problem is when I have to create large table

```
CREATE TABLE invoices
(
invoice_id INT PRIMERY_KEY  AUTO INCREMENT,
vendor_id  INT NOT NULL,
invoice_number VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
```

...

How to type this in terminal?I do not know anything about spaces and tabs?Should I use some text editor?

Comment: The whitespace just makes it prettier. You don't need newlines and tabs when typing into the mysql console.

Comment: Don't try to type anything longer than a one-line SELECT into a terminal. It's just a recipe for frustration.  Edit these in a text file, and you can execute them like `mysql -u user -p < yourfile.sql`  But if you are learning, you might also consider installing MySQL Workbench where you have a GUI editor to write queries and execute them.

Comment: @Colin__s But if the table is large 50 rows,it is the same?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks a lot,will install it for sure!

Comment: The problem with trying to do multiline things in a terminal is that you cannot go back to edit mistakes on previous lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following commands to install MySql server on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Once the setup completes you should be able to use MySql by just typing the command in the Terminal

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then the password on being prompted. You can directly enter the sql statements in the terminal then.

To exit, type

```
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XAMPP Control Panel, locate your MySQL folder in your home drive(in Windows it's C:\xampp\mysql\bin).Once you get to the bin folder, run the MySQL.exe file (again in windows: MySQL.exe -uroot -p).Replace root with the name of your administrator account. DONT change anything else. Then u should open in to the MySQL command screen. Note that in later versions of xampp, its called MariaDB and I have no idea why :-).
Happy Coding,
Anand

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04!